# Selenium 2.48.2 +firefox 42 +browser not getting instantiated

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I have upgraded to Selenium 2.48.2 from 2.46.0 and have upgraded firefox to latest version 42. After upgrade, the browser is not getting instantiated.

This is happening for all projects. I tried downgrading firefox and selenium too but it has not helped.

Please suggest!!

Following is error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
1447491412018   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1447491412018   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1447491412018   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"OsOdnf_TnA9t","location":"app-global","version":"42.0","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","installDate":1447489593709,"updateDate":1447489593709,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":24301,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"42.0","maxVersion":"42.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[]}
1447491412018   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1447491412020   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on fiddlerhook@fiddler2.com installed in winreg-app-global
1447491412030   addons.xpi  WARN    Disabling foreign installed add-on fiddlerhook@fiddler2.com in winreg-app-global
1447491412030   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon winreg-app-global:fiddlerhook@fiddler2.com visible
1447491412030   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1447491412030   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1447491412030   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"fiddlerhook@fiddler2.com","syncGUID":"mZKE2ni5yBIT","location":"winreg-app-global","version":"2.5.1.8","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":"chrome://fiddlerhook/content/about.xul","iconURL":"chrome://fiddlerhook/content/fiddlerhook.png","icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"FiddlerHook","description":"Integrate Fiddler into Firefox","creator":"Telerik","homepageURL":"https://fiddler2.com/r/?FIDDLERHOOKHELP"},"visible":true,"active":false,"userDisabled":true,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Fiddler2\\FiddlerHook","installDate":1441879129965,"updateDate":1441879129965,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":33903,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"4.0","maxVersion":"42.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0}
1447491412031   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1447491412031   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1447491412037   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1447491412059   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1447491412059   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1447491412059   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1447491412059   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1447491412059   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1447491412060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1447491412066   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1447491412067   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1447491412067   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1447491412067   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1447491412067   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1447491412068   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:276)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:223)
```

Comment: I have the same setup (windows 7, firefox 42, selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar), firefox.exe launches but the call to `driver.get(baseURL);` throws null pointer exception :( will have to check compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, Selenium Webdriver will not support latest versions of Firefox. Try downgrading to a fewer previous versions. You can try checking the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG#L112) of Selenium, there they refer to some versions that will probably work.

Then, if you want a specific previous version of Firefox, go to their [previous versions page](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/).

Comment: I did this but it is not helping. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using selenium 2.48.2 with firefox 33 which has native event support  . But as of now it will work till firefox 41 as well.
For more info check the link below >> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem a few versions back where it wasn't working after a Firefox upgrade at all even though it didn't seem that others were having any issues.

I cleared the profile and it started working for me, then I copied the cookie database into the new profile as that was a requirement that would have been difficult to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

In that situation you have two solutions:

1. downgrade your firefox and selenium version (e.g. I currently use selenium 2.46.0 with FF 41.0.1),
2. upgrade FF to 43.0 version which works fine with selenium 2.48.2