# Running protractor using firefox 44 error

Tags: firefox, protractor

I am trying to run multi browsers at once and I noticed that I cannot execute it with Firefox 44. I have already updated my selenium standalone server. 
Below is my script on config.js

```js
   

exports.config=
     {
     directConnect: true,
     seleniumAddress:'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
   capabilities: {
            'browserName': 'firefox'
            },
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```js
C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-
webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. F
irefox console output:
454955423474    addons.xpi      DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location ap
p-system-share
1454955423474   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location ap
p-system-local
1454955423475   addons.xpi      INFO    Mapping {1E2593B2-E106-4697-BCE7-A9D30DE
05D73} to C:\Program Files (x86)\HttpWatch\Firefox
1454955423475   addons.xpi      DEBUG   checkForChanges
1454955423475   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Loaded add-on state from prefs: {"app-pr
ofile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\mivy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\a
nonymous1228280274538478961webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.co
m","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1454955418766,"mt":1454955418726}},"app-global":{
"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla
Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"
v":"44.0","st":1454096785365,"mt":1454096777104}},"winreg-app-global":{"{1E2593B
2-E106-4697-BCE7-A9D30DE05D73}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HttpWatch\\Firefo
x","e":false,"v":"10.0.27","st":1440422278442,"mt":1438081200000}}}
1454955423489   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Existing add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com
in app-profile
1454955423489   addons.xpi      DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-
7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1454955423493   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285
-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
1454955423493   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Existing add-on {1E2593B2-E106-4697-BCE7
-A9D30DE05D73} in winreg-app-global
1454955423494   addons.xpi      DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {
"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\mivy\\AppData\\Local\\
Temp\\anonymous1228280274538478961webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@google
code.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1454955418766,"mt":1454955418726}},"app-gl
obal":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\M
ozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e"
:true,"v":"44.0","st":1454096785365,"mt":1454096777104}},"winreg-app-global":{"{
1E2593B2-E106-4697-BCE7-A9D30DE05D73}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HttpWatch\
\Firefox","e":false,"v":"10.0.27","st":1440422278442,"mt":1438081200000}}}
1454955423498   addons.xpi      DEBUG   No changes found
1454955423505   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProv
ider
1454955423505   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1454955423505   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManag
er
1454955423506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for Lightwe
ightThemeManager
1454955423506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightTh
emeManager
1454955423506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1454955423510   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProv
ider
1454955423510   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1454955423510   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1454955423510   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginP
rovider
1454955423510   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvide
r
1454955423511   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1454955423617   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI datab
ase C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous1228280274538478961webdriver-profi
le\extensions.json
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1454955423705   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1454955423705   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unname
d-provider>
1454955423705   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-prov
ider>
1454955423774   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1454955423774   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI datab
ase, parsing...
1454955423775   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
1454955423830   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentPro
vider
1454955423830   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for Previou
sExperimentProvider
1454955423830   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExper
imentProvider

    at new bot.Error (C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:106:9)

    at C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\se
lenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:158:24
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\Users\mivy\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\
webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.
js:563:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promi
se.js:552:16)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roami
ng\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\web
driver.js:155:22)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdr
iver.js:129:30)
    at [object Object].Builder.build (C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\builder.js:416:22)
    at [object Object].DriverProvider.getNewDriver (C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roamin
g\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:38:7)
    at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:180:37)
    at C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:2
56:21
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\nod
e_modules\q\q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\mivy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:759:13)
    at C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\
q.js:525:49
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Is there anything that I missed on configuration? Or is it that I need to upgrade my plugin in firefox? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/669#issuecomment-39467873

Comment: are you talking about     seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/selenium/IEDriverServer.exe']
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Protractor 3.0.0, the Firefox-related issue should be solved by upgrading it to the, currently latest, *version 43*. The Firefox 42 has [compatibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706711/selenium-2-48-2-firefox-42-browser-not-getting-instantiated) with selenium 2.48.

Comment: I am using the 2.2.0 I think I need to update my protractor then